# Hide radio buttons and just show labels in django form (radio select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I want to remove the radio buttons and just show the yes or no labels. In order to do that I hid the radio input and used the css3 selector (:checked + label) to change background color according to selection. But this is not working for some reason.

**HTML (from Django Template)**

```
<div class="questionnaire-radio">
    <label>
        <input class="selector" name="mdq_answer_1"   required="True" type="radio" value="y"> yes
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.questionnaire-radio input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.questionnaire-radio input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-color:  #28c3ab;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.questionnaire-radio label {
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid #28c3ab;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.questionnaire-radio label:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #28c3ab;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am using Chrome as my browser. I am open to jQuery solutions (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

To use the input[type=radio]:checked + label the way you want things need to be formatted a certain way.  Input needs to be above the label you are trying to access

see it working in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QBM5/egv8K/1/

```
<div class="questionnaire-radio">
<input id="aaa" class="selector" name="mdq_answer_1"   required="True" type="radio" value="y"  />
<label for="aaa">yes</label> 

<input id="bbb" class="selector" name="mdq_answer_1"   required="True" type="radio" value="n" />
<label for="bbb">no</label>
```

I made some assumptions and added some markup to make sure it worked,  but you should be able to get it to work following this example.

Comment: This works in plain html, but for some reason not in django.

Comment: lol, two years later... Inspect the html after rendering and see what is different, platforms like django shouldnt effect how html css behave, so it likely changed the html somehow

Comment: Turned out to be a PEBKAC error where there was a typo in my for field.  Certainly a case of check multiple times before commenting on someone's stack overflow.